# PySpark optimize left join of two big tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using the most updated version of PySpark on Databricks. I have two tables each of the size ~25-30GB. I want to join Table1 and Table2 at the "id" and "id_key" columns respectively. I'm able to do that with the command below but when I run my spark job the join is skewed resulting in +95% of my data on one executor making the job take forever. This is happening when I attempt to load the data after transforming it.

Table1 has 13 total columns where the "id" column has a lot of null values with some actual id values.

Table2 has 3 total columns where "id_key" has all possible id values each appearing once.

I tried broadcasting but because the tables are pretty large, I get OutOfMemory errors when running the job

```
Table1.join(Table2, Table1.id == Table2.id_key, "left")
```

I'm thinking of salting but not sure how to go about that or if it is the right solution.

Comment: which version of databricks run time are you using ?

Comment: Version DBR 8.1

Comment: @AnandVidvat  ^^^^

Comment: You can also try to look at your `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` within your cluster configuration , a useful link about performance tuning can be found here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: In order to get better insight into your problem, can you post a screenshot of the Web UI Stage Detail page for the problem stage?

Comment: Posting the code that reads the two tables would also help others to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your problem, I guess Spark must put all rows with `null` id in `Table1` in the same partition during join's partitioning.

To solve this, you can use the following pattern:

- split `Table1` dataframe between *null ids dataframe* and *not null ids dataframe*
- join your *not null ids dataframe* with `Table2`
- add columns of `Table2` with null value to *null ids dataframe*
- union the obtained *not null ids dataframe* and *null ids dataframe*

You can find below the code translation of this pattern:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Table1_with_null_ids = Table1.filter(F.col('id').isNull())
Table1_with_not_null_ids = Table1.filter(F.col('id').isNotNull())

Table1_with_not_null_ids_joined = Table1_with_not_null_ids.join(
  Table2, 
  Table1_with_not_null_ids.id == Table2.id_key, 
  'left'
)

Table1_with_null_ids_joined = Table1_with_null_ids \
  .withColumn('id_key', F.lit(None)) \
  .withColumn('table2_column2', F.lit(None)) \
  .withColumn('table2_column3', F.lit(None))

Table1_joined = Table1_with_not_null_ids_joined.unionByName(Table1_with_null_ids_joined)
```

It avoids doing manual salting, and it may improve performance as you join `Table2` with much less rows on `Table1` side

However you need to compute the input `Table1` two times as you perform `filter` two times on the same `Table1`. If computing input `Table1` is an expensive process, you can either cache `Table1` before double filtering or proceed as you suggested and add a salting column to `Table1` and `Table2` and use it in your join expression.